# Method invoked when a test throws an Exception

Tags: java, android, android-testing

I'm having some troubles with testing in Android.
For each test I do, I have a common set of instructions to do before the test and after the test. So, the idea would be define a `setUp()` and `tearDown()` method.

So far so good. The problem is that, apparently, the `tearDown()` method is not invoked when the test "fails" (that means when the tests throws an `Exception`).

Is there a method that can be invoked when a test throws an Exception or a "tricky" way to do this?

Comment: `try{...} catch (...) {...}`?

Comment: But I want it to work like the `tearDown()` method. Using `try{...} catch (...) {...}` makes me write the code for every test, and I don't want that.

Comment: Sorry dude... better safe than sorry, and BTW, what harm is a little _copy-paste_ gonna do?

Comment: But I have almost 200 tests, and I'me using an instrumentation tool to automatically generate the `tearDown()` and `setUp()` methods

Comment: Okay... that's a bigger prob than I expected...

Comment: I can't seem to find another way out though... get ready for a _really-long-editing-session_, play some music, sit back and **edit**! Good Luck! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Test like this:

```
try{
    setUp();
    /* do some testing*/
}catch(Exception ex){
    /* do something with the exception */
    /* let the test fail */
}finally{
    tearDown();
}
```

It's probably the easiest solution for your problem, but from the viewpoint of good design practice this should be avoided.

edit:

There are annotations in jUnit: [Different teardown for each @Test in jUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830342/different-teardown-for-each-test-in-junit)

edit2:

> The setUp() method is invoked before every test. You use it to
>   initialize variables and clean up from previous tests. You can also
>   use the JUnit tearDown() method, which runs after every test method.
>   The tutorial does not use it.

http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_test.html

If you have different `tearDown()` Methods for each test, I think you need to change them.

Comment: _ahem [coughs] ahem_?

Comment: Like I said to #ambigram_maker, I don't want to alter the tests. I want to know if there's a way to defie somehow that when a test (generically) fails, a method is invoked. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Well... since the `tearDown()` method is invoked after every test, I'm not using any annotation. But is there an annotation I can use for my problem?

Comment: If you don't want to change anything in the tests, make the `tearDown()` method work so that it's invariant if you call it more than once. Add and `After`- or `AfterClass`-Annotation to the Tests and it should be ok.

Comment: For some reason I can't use the `@After` ou `@AfterClass` annotations. My project doesn't recognize it. I tried to add jUnit library to the classpath, but still nothing. Any idea?